# Uploading images from different imageViews to the server

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to upload two images from two `ImageViews` to the server but I'm challenged. When I try with one `ImageView` it works but two `ImageViews`, it doesn't.

```
<ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:src="@drawable/id_card"/>
    
       <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:src="@drawable/ref_card"/>
```

My `requestCode` looks like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_ONE);



  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_TWO);
```

My `onActivityResult` code looks like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


                if(requestCode == IMAGE_ONE)
                    imageView1.setImageBitmap(imageOne);
                else if(requestCode == IMAGE_TWO)
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(imageTwo);
            }
```

Then,

```
    BitmapDrawable drawable1 = (BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable();
BitmapDrawable drawable2 = (BitmapDrawable) imageView2.getDrawable();

Bitmap idCardBitmap = drawable1.getBitmap();
Bitmap refIdBitmap = drawable2.getBitmap();

final String image1 = getStringImage(idCardBitmap);
final String image2 = getStringImage(refIdBitmap);

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

To `upload`,

```
ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getApiService();
        Call<ResponseBody> call = api.registerDetails(image1,image2)
```

Comment: If the problem is with the upload part you should add your upload function to the question

Comment: @MatPag I have edited

Comment: `imageView1.setImageBitmap(imageOne)` ?? What is imageOne? And what is imageTwo? What do they have to do with ACTION_PICK?

Comment: If you select an image with ACTION_PICK and you want to upload the selected file then do not first put it in an ImageView from where you do a lot of effort to extract it from. Better use the obtained uri directly. Redesign your app.